# Compute the width of a string in monspaced font

Tags: perl, unicode, text-formatting

In order to properly format some text in a terminal (where I assume usage of a monospaced font), I need to compute the “length” of strings. The tricky part is that I need the length it will use on display (in number of fixed-width characters).

I originally used the [length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) function, but it returns the number of **codepoints**. I also tried to count the number of **graphemes** using:

```
sub width {
    my $str = shift;
    my $count = 0;
    while ($str =~ /\X/g) {
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

(Credits to [Tom Christiansen](https://www.perl.com/pub/2012/05/perlunicook-string-length-in-graphemes.html/)).

But this is still not what I need, as some graphemes are double-width with my font (SF Mono Regular), e.g. emojis and Asian characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further research, I found the [Text::CharWidth](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CharWidth) CPAN module, which provides the `mbswidth` function, doing exactly what I need.

```
use Text::CharWidth qw(mbswidth);

mbswidth (""); # returns 4
mbswidth ("あら"); # returns 4
```